# SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups Licencing

Tags: sql-server

I am planning to implement SQL Server 2014 Always ON Availability Groups between 2 nodes(servers) and using SQL server Enterprise edition on top of WSFC, Node1 is primary replica(read/Write)  and Node2 is secondary replica  and databases are Restoring mode only and will not use or read/write  data until disaster (failover)happens

as per documentation , SQL server Agent should run on both servers at anytime but only Primary Replica's  jobs executes at anytime using Some checks.

Question1:

do i have  to pay for both licences node1 and node2?

Note: node1 will be primary and node 2 is secondary and only when failover happens node 2 will become active but i will have sql agent running on both nodes at any given time ...

Question2:

do i have  to pay for both licences node1 and node2?

If i disable SQL Agent  on Node2 and manually enable the SQL Agent when failover happens on node2?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Passive failover rights` were changed with SQL 2014. While those rights were previously part of the server license, you now only have those rights if you have `Software Assurance`.

> Passive fail-over rights permit a customer to run passive instances of SQL Server in a separate operating system environment (OSE) without requiring the passive server to be licensed for SQL Server.  A passive SQL Server instance is one that is not serving SQL Server data to clients or running active SQL Server workloads.

See http://blogs.technet.com/b/volume-licensing/archive/2014/05/29/licensing-how-to-sql-2014-licensing-changes.aspx

So, if you don't have `Software Assurance`, you will probably have to pay for both licenses.

I don't believe you need to disable SQL Agent, as long as all client connections and jobs (including backups) only run against the online database. I'd be careful if you are configuring multiple availability groups as one failing over and not the other would require you to license the second server.

Comment: ex: at node1 sql agent JOB "XYZ" runs every 2 minutes check if PRIMARY--then Execeute the SP at node2 same job "XYZ" runs every 2 minutes check if PRIMARY then execute else if secondary do nothing ...at any given time 2 sql agents run but only one JOB XYZ executes SP...

Comment: jmc, We do have software assurance in our company for ent.edition.  The question now, is a server must be licensed to have an active SQL Agent service, which is not serving clients or running any backup or maintenance jobs but check as above example

Comment: You probably shouldn't take my word for it, since I don't work for Microsoft, but I'm pretty sure that isn't a problem. You don't have to disable the `SQL Server service` with `passive failover rights`, so why would you need to disable `SQL Agent`? You need to have the server ready to take over for any failure. Having your jobs already configured and scheduled is an important part of that.